# Problems with de-registering of COM (advanced installer)

Tags: c++, windows, com, advanced-installer

Definition of problem:

Hangs up for sometime during COM de-registering and says `The setup was unable to automatically close all requested applications. Please ensure that the applications holding files in use are closed before continuing with the installation`. But actually my extension is successfully unloaded and uninstalled.

Definition of environment:

I created some kind of dummy shell namespace extension for tests. It implements `IContextMenu` and all methods return`S_OK` and do nothing else and rgs file is

```
HKCR
{
    xxx.sergz.dummyShellExt.1 = s 'DummyNSE Class'
    {
        CLSID = s '{6C0FBE00-9898-4BB0-806F-3ED7D2F1170D}'
    }
    xxx.sergz.dummyShellExt = s 'DummyNSE Class'
    {
        CurVer = s 'xxx.sergz.dummyShellExt.1'
    }
    NoRemove CLSID
    {
        ForceRemove {6C0FBE00-9898-4BB0-806F-3ED7D2F1170D} = s 'DummyNSE Class'
        {
            ProgID = s 'xxx.sergz.dummyShellExt.1'
            VersionIndependentProgID = s 'xxx.sergz.dummyShellExt'
            ForceRemove Programmable
            InprocServer32 = s '%MODULE%'
            {
                val ThreadingModel = s 'Apartment'
            }
            TypeLib = s '{3DC947F0-6691-4043-B414-29F749209905}'
            Version = s '1.0'
        }
    }
    NoRemove Directory
    {
        NoRemove Background
        {
            NoRemove ShellEx
            {
                NoRemove ContextMenuHandlers
                {
                   ForceRemove DummyShellExt = s '{6C0FBE00-9898-4BB0-806F-3ED7D2F1170D}'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


HKLM
{
  NoRemove Software
  {
    NoRemove Microsoft
    {
      NoRemove Windows
      {
        NoRemove CurrentVersion
        {
          NoRemove Shell Extensions
          {
            NoRemove Approved
            {
              val '{6C0FBE00-9898-4BB0-806F-3ED7D2F1170D}' = s 'xxx.sergz Dummy shell extension.'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I choose `Professional` installer and added only my dll file. On file properties `Registration` tab I choose `Auto register file...`, `Extract registration info...` and `Synchronization` is `Enabled`. In `Product Information->Install Parameters->PackageType` I choose `64-bit package for x64...`.

Now I build the MSI and install the extension.
Launch explorer and do right click somewhere on folder background. According to my log my extension is loaded and is DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH and a few times DLL_THREAD_ATTACH.

I launch the MSI again and choose `Remove`. It says that you have to close `... applications are using files...` and there is only `Windows Explorer` in the list. I choose `Automatically close ...` and press OK.

All Explorer windows are closed but it seems that Explorer was not shutdown.

The status is "Shutting down applications", according to my log the dll is already unloaded. The problem is here. The dll is already unloaded but the MSI is still waiting for something and then it says `The setup was unable to automatically close all requested applications. Please ensure that the applications holding files in use are closed before continuing with the installation`.
I click OK and the process continues and my DLL is successfully removed in the end.

I use windows 8 64bit.

What are the reasons of this waiting and the message that applications can not be closed. How can I figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Right, this isn't going to work, the shell extension is very likely to be loaded and MSI isn't going to kill Explorer.exe.  Nor would you want it to, it is rather a ghastly sight to the user.

You'll need to use an alternative way to un/register the extension.  It isn't clear what "Professional installer" might mean.  But you can always un/register a COM server by modifying the registry yourself rather than leaving it up to the DLL to do so.  It is in fact the recommended way.  You already know the registry keys from your .rgs file.  You can also use the Heat.exe harvester from the WiX toolset.  The DLL needs to be removed by delay-deleting it at the next user login, done by adding it to the PendingFileRenameOperations registry key.  Check your installer creator tool for the proper procedure.

Comment: "Professional installer" -> http://advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-professional.html . Of cource I can use WiX, but the question is about advanced installer. Actually there is the same situation, according to steps to reproduce the problem, advanced installer extracts rgs from the DLL, I don't use self registering/unregistering. The DLL also can be removed almost immediately, without re-login. It's a question of installer tool, it asks user to automatically close applications using opened files or to restart computer.